# Windows Server 2012 R2 inicia con perfil de red publico

Tags: dominio, windows-server-2012, firewall

Tengo un servidor con Windows Server 2012 R2 unido a un dominio, cuando se reinicia el servidor por cualquier motivo, inicia con el perfil de red Publico, con lo cual me bloquea todos los accesos de red hacia el, lo cual esta bien, pero necesito que este en el perfil de Dominio donde tengo configurados algunos puertos que debe permitir y otros no.

De hecho, solo me permite cambiar al perfil privado, no al de dominio y no me permite cambiar las opciones de deteccion de redes, al seleccionar la "Activar" y guardar los cambios no los aplica[image: deteccion de redes automatico]

Agradecido de antemano quien pueda orientarme

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: te pregunta es sobre configuración de Sistema Operativo y no es sobre un problema de Programación, tu pregunta seria mejor recibida en https://superuser.com/